InAppBillingImplementation does not exist (Xamarin Forms, Android)
Version Number of InAppBilling Plugin: 7.13
Device Tested On: N/A
Simulator Tested On: N/A
Version of VS: Visual Studio Mac 17.6.13 (build 424)
Version of Xamarin: 5.0.0.2515
Versions of other things you are using: N/A
Steps to reproduce the Behavior
N/A
Expected Behavior
The code should compile.
Actual Behavior
I'm trying to upgrade InAppBilling to submit the app to the store.
The code does not compile and produces the error: "InAppBillingImplementation does not exist" when I upgrade to version 7.13.
However, this class does exist in Android InAppBilling.
The last working version was 7.0.5.
Code snippet & Screenshot

